# sscanf is well but std::scanf don't work

Tags: c++, std, scanf

I'm trying to read from a text file using Visual Studio 2010 Pro. `sscanf` works well, but `std::scanf` does not.

I don't know why this happens; please help me.

```
float b, g, r;
int px = 0;
int py = 0;
std::string strLine;  // some string is.

//below code works very well.
int nRead = sscanf(strLine.c_str(), "%f %f %f %d %d", &b, &g, &r, &px, &py );

//but this does not.
int nRead = std::scanf(strLine.c_str(), "%f %f %f %d %d", &b, &g, &r, &px, &py );
```

Comment: how about `std::sscanf`?

Answer (score 3):

From the manual page:

```
   int scanf(const char *format, ...);
   int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
   int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

- scanf: read from stdin
- fscanf: read from FILE
- sscanf: read from string.

The way you invoked scanf, the intended string to read from is interpreted as the format specification, while the format spececification is used as one of the variable arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices:

```
int nRead = std::sscanf(strLine.c_str(), "%f %f %f %d %d", &b, &g, &r, &px, &py );
```

or

```
int nRead = std::scanf("%f %f %f %d %d", &b, &g, &r, &px, &py );
```

pick one.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using them correctly. Check out [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) for `std::scanf`, `std::fscanf` and `std::sscanf` on cppreference.com.

[image]

You probably want to use:

```
std::sscanf(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

std::scanf is used to read content from stdin.

std::sscanf is used to read from string.

[Click the link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)